# Does <httpRedirect> in web.config work in a mono setup? Or is it IIS7 specific?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, mono, web-config

We had some content restructure recently and I'd like to put in some redirect rules into web.config so bookmarks to the old pages can get routed to their new locations/pages.

I tried using this approach:

```
<location path="~/product/productA.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="~/product/category/productA.aspx" exactDestination="false" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But all I'm getting when I go to "http://www.oursite.com/product/productA.aspx" is our http 404 page.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the httpRedirect tag in web.config not supported in mono?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is an IIS 7 specific tag, so you should not expect it work for any other platforms. No IIS 5/6, and no Mono.